# Distributed Tensorflow Tensorforest

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, parallel-processing, distributed-computing, random-forest

Please I am new in distributed processing and I  want to knowHow can we train tensorforest model using distributed tensorforest ? I understood how it's done for the neural networks but I did not  for the  tensorforest which is a Random forest implemantation using  tensorflow framework

Answer (score 0):

I have recently delved into this topic. Since `TensorForestEstimator` is derived from `tf.contrib.learn.Estimator`, it should be possible to use it in a distributed training environment.

The problem I have run into is how to configure device assignment properly.  The constructor for the `TensorForestEstimator` takes a `device_assigner` keyword argument.

`device_assigner: An object instance that controls how trees get assigned to devices. If None, will use tensor_forest.RandomForestDeviceAssigner.`

The documentation isn't accurate.  The default is actually an instance of `tf.contrib.framework.VariableDeviceChooser`.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/contrib/tensor_forest/python/tensor_forest.py#L380

The code instantiates `VariableDeviceChooser` with no arguments, which it should be run with no parameter servers.  That's fine on a single machine environment, but not so in a distributed environment.  I've tried passing a value of `VariableDeviceChooser` instantiated  with the number of parameter servers inferred from data in `TF_CONFIG`.

This is the error message I observe as a session is initiated during a training operation.

````
  File "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/cmle-1_12-py-3_5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1334, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/cmle-1_12-py-3_5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1317, in _run_fn
    self._extend_graph()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/cmle-1_12-py-3_5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1352, in _extend_graph
    tf_session.ExtendSession(self._session)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation device_dummy_0/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform: Could not satisfy explicit device specification '' because the node {{colocation_node device_dummy_0/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform}} was colocated with a group of nodes that required incompatible device '/job:ps/task:0/device:CPU:0'
Colocation Debug Info:
Colocation group had the following types and devices: 
IsVariableInitialized: CPU 
Assign: CPU 
Identity: CPU XLA_CPU 
VariableV2: CPU  
Mul: CPU XLA_CPU 
Add: CPU XLA_CPU 
Sub: CPU XLA_CPU 
RandomUniform: CPU XLA_CPU 
Const: CPU XLA_CPU 

Colocation members and user-requested devices:
  device_dummy_0/Initializer/random_uniform/shape (Const) 
  device_dummy_0/Initializer/random_uniform/min (Const) 
  device_dummy_0/Initializer/random_uniform/max (Const) 
  device_dummy_0/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform (RandomUniform) 
  device_dummy_0/Initializer/random_uniform/sub (Sub) 
  device_dummy_0/Initializer/random_uniform/mul (Mul) 
  device_dummy_0/Initializer/random_uniform (Add) 
  device_dummy_0 (VariableV2) /job:ps/task:0/device:CPU:0   
  device_dummy_0/Assign (Assign) /job:ps/task:0/device:CPU:0
  device_dummy_0/read (Identity) /job:ps/task:0/device:CPU:0
  report_uninitialized_variables/IsVariableInitialized_1 (IsVariableInitialized) /job:ps/task:0/device:CPU:0  
  report_uninitialized_variables_1/IsVariableInitialized_1 (IsVariableInitialized) /job:ps/task:0/device:CPU:0
  save/Assign_1 (Assign) /job:ps/task:0/device:CPU:0

     [[{{node device_dummy_0/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform}} = RandomUniform[T=DT_INT32, _class=["loc:@device_dummy_0"], dtype=DT_FLOAT, seed=0, seed2=0](device_dummy_0/Initializer/random_uniform/shape)]]```
````